# What Sass-like options are available for PHP (and being maintained)?

Tags: php, css, sass

I'm looking to add a little magic to my CSS in some PHP projects (running Sass in watch mode isn't a viable option in this case), but I can't find anything that fits the bill. My criteria are:

- Easy to integrate into PHP applications regardless of framework
- Being maintained
- Syntax is CSS-compliant (which rules out Less and a few others)

The solution doesn't necessarily have to be pure PHP, but it should be ideal for integrating with PHP projects.

I realise this is a recurring question, but since the last time it was answered a lot has changed (PHamlP appears to have died, for one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) fits into your requirements. See this [slideshare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/assetic-symfony-live-paris) for more info.

In general Assetic is an asset management framework that includes for example filters that can handle SASS, SCSS or even Compass. Internally they just call the appropriate executable and filter the input.

Comment: This looks really great, thanks! For those reading this that haven't seen it, it's an asset manager for PHP to handle CSS & Javascript, and you can add on filters such as compressors, rewriters, or interpreters for things like SASS and CoffeeScript.